# Show strings separated by commas

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show contact numbers separated by commas But i am not able to do it. Right now I am able to show them line by line.How to show them like 9999999999,8888888888....etc
Below is my code snippet

```
 try {
            int pos = 0;
            for (Contact contact : contacts) {
                String displayName = contact.getPhone(0);
                result.append(displayName + ",");
                result.setSpan(new BulletSpan(15), pos, pos + displayName.length() + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                pos += displayName.length() + 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.append(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: do you know the purpose of using "\n"?

Comment: `I am trying to show contact numbers separated by commas` -- Where is your attempt to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting next line because you are appending `\n`

To get comma separated replace "\n" with ","

```
String displayName = contact.getPhone(0);
                result.append(displayName + ",");
```

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you that the next question is gonna be about how to get rid of the trailing comma ;)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeh I know that. As you know we do not give spoon feeding answers so intentionally I did not add

Comment: yeah can u tell hw to remove that trailing comma

Comment: this is going to be another question, please read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

\n used to print new line so put comma symbol (',') instead of \n

```
   result.append(contact.getPhone(0)+ ",");//for one person no
```